# Adding logo next to Toggle Icon on navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fresh to HTML & CSS. I have started customizing a Bootstrap template and would like to add a logo next to the icon bar, but this navbar seems way more trickier than the basic Bootstrap navbar that I've played around with. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out by pointing me where to look in the code, or by providing one or two examples. Here is the [link](http://affapress.com/templates/upsite_responsive_corporate_landing_page/html/header_4/) to the template I am customizing. I would like to place an image right next to the toggle button like [this](http://affapress.com/) one does with "Menu".

HTML:

```
<nav id="navigation" class="navbar scrollspy">

    <!-- .container -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a> <!-- site logo -->
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#header" class="smooth-scroll">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" class="smooth-scroll">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#features" class="smooth-scroll">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolios" class="smooth-scroll">Portfolios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#whyus" class="smooth-scroll">Why Us?</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html">Page</a></li>
            <li class="menu-btn"><a href="page_contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- .container end -->

</nav>
```

CSS:

```css
/* Navigation Mobile */
#navigation_mobile {
    display:none;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:18px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:600;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#navigation_mobile .nav-menu-links {
    display:none;
    background-color:#2a2a2a;
}
#navigation_mobile ul {
    padding:30px 100px;
    margin:0px;
}
#navigation_mobile ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:11px 0px;
}
#navigation_mobile ul li a {
    display:block;
    color:#a9a9a9;
}
#navigation_mobile ul li a:hover { color:#FFF; }
#navigation_mobile .nav-menu-button {
    background-color:#202020;
    padding:15px 0px 14px;
}
#navigation_mobile .nav-menu-button button.nav-menu-toggle {
    color:#a9a9a9 !important;
    font-size:24px;
    line-height:1;
    background:none;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    border-radius:0px;
    -webkit-transition:color .2s ease;
    transition:color .2s ease;
}
#navigation_mobile .nav-menu-button button.nav-menu-toggle:hover { color:#FFF !important; }

#header .navbar { display:none;}
#navigation_mobile { display:block; }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry I have fixed the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add the text to the image. And define the text in the image by:

```
<img src="logo.png" alt="My Logo">
```

Comment: I am sorry I dont understand your answer. I am trying to add the logo image to the toggle icon!